# Yeoman ASP MVC install Visual Studio Code - Unexpected Token '}'

Tags: node.js, yeoman

I'm trying to build a ASP.NET 5 MVC application using Visual Studio Code.

I'm trying to run `yo aspnet` but I'm getting the following error:

```
Andrews-MBP:~ ad$ yo aspnet
undefined:25
  }
  ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token }
    at Object.parse (native)
    at EditionInterface.module.exports [as readJSON] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-aspnet/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/mem-fs-editor/actions/read-json.js:5:17)
    at Base.determineAppname (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-aspnet/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/base.js:740:25)
    at Base (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-aspnet/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/base.js:145:23)
    at new yeoman.generators.Base.extend.constructor (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-aspnet/app/index.js:10:32)
    at Environment.instantiate (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/yeoman-environment/lib/environment.js:282:10)
    at Environment.create (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/yeoman-environment/lib/environment.js:259:15)
    at Environment.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/yeoman-environment/lib/environment.js:318:24)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/lib/cli.js:86:9
    at Environment.resolver.lookup (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/yeoman-environment/lib/resolver.js:50:12)
```

I'm following this guide: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/aspnet5

I'm not an expert at node nor OS X for that matter. Is this a bug in Yeoman / ASP.NET 5 for VSC?

Answer (score 1):

hey I was having a similar issue and I updated the node version, re installed yeoman and the aspnet generator and then it worked for me.

To update node I followed the David Walsh blog post (http://davidwalsh.name/upgrade-nodejs)

and then reinstall yeoman and the aspnet generator:

- npm install -g yo
- npm install -g generator-aspnet

I hope it works.

Comment: I had a similar problem except my unexpected token was "{" instead of "}".  I was trying to use node version 8.17.0 because of dependencies that are out of my control.  I switched to node version 10.19.0 and yeoman installed fine.  Now I hopefully can still revert to node 8.17.0 after using the yeoman generator.